# check quota inside debian openvz vps

Tags: debian, openvz, quota

How I can check the user quota inside a debian openvz vps ?

The user's mail quota looks wrong; I have this error:

procmail: Quota exceeded while writing "/xxxx/Maildir/tmp/xxxxxxxxxx.com"

but the user quota looks under his limit.

Answer (score 0):

Check your diskspace and inodes inside the VPS:

vzctl exec  ps -f # for diskspace

vzctl exec  ps -i # for inode usage

In case some of them are out of boundary correct them;

vzctl set  --diskinodes [minvalue]:[maxvalue] --save

vzctl set  --diskspace [min]GB:[max]GB --save